# Java inherited variable returns null

Tags: java, object, inheritance, arraylist, null

When i try to use a variable from superclass "arxiki" in a subclass, it returns null value. Basically i store the objects in an ArrayList and i want to print them so i use toString() method. I have initialized the variables, used super() in the subclass so i can't find whats wrong.

```
public class arxiki{
private String onoma;
private int pagio;
public arxiki(String onoma, int pagio){
    this.onoma=onoma;
    this.pagio=pagio;
}
public arxiki(){
}
public arxiki(String onoma){
}
public String getOnoma(){
    return onoma;
}
public int getPagio(){
    return pagio;
}

public String toString() {
    return "\nOnoma: "+getOnoma();
}
```

The sub-class of "arxiki"

```
public class symvolaio extends arxiki{
private int kodikos;
private String onomateponimo;
private String tilefono;
private String imerominia;
private String troposexoflisis;
public symvolaio(String onoma,int kodikos, String onomateponimo, String tilefono, String imerominia, String troposexoflisis){//symvolaioconstructor
    super(onoma);
    this.kodikos=kodikos;
    this.onomateponimo=onomateponimo;
    this.tilefono=tilefono;
    this.imerominia=imerominia;
    this.troposexoflisis=troposexoflisis;
}
public symvolaio(int kodikos){
}
public int getKodikos(){
    return kodikos;
}
public String getOnomateponimo(){
    return onomateponimo;
}
public String getTilefono(){
    return tilefono;
}
public String getImerominia(){
    return imerominia;
}
public String getTroposexoflisis(){
    return troposexoflisis;
}

public String toString(){
    return super.toString()+", Kodikos: "+getKodikos()+", Onomateponimo: "+getOnomateponimo()+", Tilefono: "+getTilefono()+", Imerominia Enarxis: "+getImerominia()+", Tropos Exoflisis: " + getTroposexoflisis();
}
}
```

And lastly the part of a loop where the objects inside the ArrayList are printed

```
Iterator <symvolaio> iterator = listasymvolaion.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                System.out.printf(listasymvolaion.get(k).toString());
                k++;
```

Comment: you _are_ calling ``super(onoma)``, but take a look at what that constructor does...

Comment: That was it thank you!

Comment: Note that it's really good practice to make member variables final unless they *really* need to be mutable. Then you can be sure that you always initialize them.

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming conventions. Class names start UpperCase; always. And use the @Override annotation for methods that *override* something.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions everyone

Comment: *"unrelated"* — "Unrelated, but yet **very important**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor you are calling from the subclass looks like this:

```
public arxiki(String onoma){
}
```

which is obviously lacking the assignment, add this to the constructor's body:

```
 this.onoma=onoma;
```